# Rad scheduler blocks the functionality after finger goes on it

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik, radscheduler

I am working on asp.net MVC.I am trying to integrate Telerik Rad Scheduler into my project. I need Drag and Drop, editing and inserting features of Radscheduler and it needs to work in all devices (tablets,desktops except mobile). However i satisfied all the above requirements. But i have a major problem that i am not able to make this work in android tablet, Each appointment in my scheduler had buttons to move up and down with in particular slots and also edit button to edit appointment, It will works very well **until your finger doesn't goes into the scheduler area(empty scheduler area), once you gone into scheduler area it will blocks and hangs the scheduler functionality**. and even i tested with firebug remote debugging i didn't find the solution for this. I am using jquery for remaining functionality to work. Please guide me if any other factors might cause scheduler not to work. Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked with Telerik whether it's supported on Android?

Comment: Well it works very fine in  Android default browser but it doesn't work in Google Chrome browser in Android.